# Integrate $\int\sqrt{25\sin^2(5x)+49\cos^2(7x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have tried solving the following integral using Calc I&II methods and couldn't find an answer.
I would like to know the techniques for solving such integral.

$$\int\sqrt{25\sin^2(5x)+49\cos^2(7x)}dx$$

Comment: If it does Wolfram doesn't know about it.

Comment: It is the arc length of a [Lissajous curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LissajousCurve.html) and it is very likely related to (hyper-)elliptic integrals. What is the original purpose of computing such primitive?

Comment: Most likely there is no closed formula, as pointed out in problem 10 in here:http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/summer2011/handouts/24-arclength.pdf